# Android Studio 1.5 and HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I just installed the update to Android Studio v. 1.5 and some package updates. I installed HAXM, but then when opening AVD emulators, I get the message "HAXM is not installed, install now?"

When I click to install, it seems to be installing, but if I click "show details" I can see the following error:

> Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-intel-hardware_accelerated_execution_manager'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.

The installation finishes but isn't properly installed (AVD devices drag and freeze on loading).

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling HAXM, rebooting the computer.

Running Mac El Capitan.

UPDATE: So HAXM IS installed, but this was an error with one virtual device and RAM size. I think I've got it figured out, will post answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer: You get that error if you try to run HAXM with less RAM than the virtual device settings. Changed device to match HAXM ram, no problem.